# regex not capturing newline

Tags: regex, logging, newline

I am trying to parse log files using regex. logs looks like that:

```
2022-04-01 00:00:00.0000|DEBUG|LOREM:LOREM|IPSUM:LOREM:LOREMIPSUM Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel placerat sapien. Suspendisse interdum est nulla, ac interdum sem pellentesque vel. Ut condimentum nisl ipsum (Failed:1/Total:5) [10.0000 ms].
2022-04-01 00:00:00.0000|DEBUG|LOREM:IPSUM|lorem ipsum \\SOME-PATH[Lorem Ipsum] (ID:000000-0000-0000-0000). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel placerat sapien. Suspendisse interdum est nulla, ac interdum sem pellentesque vel. //line return here
Ut condimentum nisl ipsum.
2022-04-01 00:00:00.0000|DEBUG|LOREM:IPSUM|lorem ipsum \\SOME-PATH[Lorem Ipsum] (ID:000000-0000-0000-0000). Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel placerat sapien. Suspendisse interdum est nulla, ac interdum sem pellentesque vel. //line return here
Ut condimentum nisl ipsum.
```

Here is what I have tried (live version on regex 101 https://regex101.com/r/RoDU5L/1)

```
^(?<timestamp>^[\d-]+\s[\d:.]+)\|DEBUG\|(.*?)?\r?$|.*?(?<path>\\.*\]\s)(?<description>.*)+$ /gm
```

The problem is that it is not taking the last line "Ut condimentum nisl ipsum."

Thanks for your help

Comment: What about https://regex101.com/r/RoDU5L/2?

Comment: It works thanks, didnt know about the negative lookahead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?<timestamp>^[\d-]+\s[\d:.]+)\|DEBUG\|(.*(?:\r?\n(?![\d-]+\s[\d:.]+\|).*)*)|.*?(?<path>\\.*\]\s)(?<description>.*)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RoDU5L/2).

The `.*(?:\r?\n(?![\d-]+\s[\d:.]+\|).*)*` part now matches

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(?:\r?\n(?![\d-]+\s[\d:.]+\|).*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\r?\n(?![\d-]+\s[\d:.]+\|)` - CRLF or LF line ending now immediately followed with a datetime-like pattern and a `|` right after
  - `.*`  - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that the path is not captured

Comment: @EASameh Which is the path? I just fixed the immediate issue, if you have others, please describe.

Comment: What I meant is that in the second alternative (your OR), the "path" and "description" group are not captured. 
In your demo, it would apply for the seond and third match. The path would be \\SOME-PATH[Lorem Ipsum] and description would be "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel placerat sapien. Suspendisse interdum est nulla, ac interdum sem pellentesque vel. //line return here" Hope you can understand what i meant

Comment: @EASameh That sounds complex. Try `^(?<timestamp>^[\d-]+\s[\d:.]+)\|DEBUG\|(?:.*?(?<path>\\[^\]]*\])\s*\([^()]*\)\W*|[A-Z:|]+\s*)(?<description>.*(?:\n(?![\d-]+\s[\d:.]+\|).*)*)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RoDU5L/3). Running on assumptions now.